# How to minus date from sysdate using oracle inline query?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am creating one query. In that query i want minus date from system date. My table is like below.

```
Table Name : Employee
---------------------
ID
NAME
JOINDATE
```

I am writing this query to fetch my result

```
SELECT * FROM SS.EMPLOYEE WHERE (sysdate - JOINDATE)='05-Ded-11'
```

This throws the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

So how to do this???If anyone knows than please help me.

Comment: Is `JOINDATE` a number? Otherwise you're subtracting a date from date, which would result in a number.  Also, is `Ded` in `'05-Ded-11'` a typo?

Comment: "*But it giving me an error...*" is not a valid oracle error message.

Comment: @beny23: No its not a number. Its date field.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I know its not oracle error. I have written description not an error message

Comment: And how should we know which error that is if you don't show it to us? You **have** to show the exact error message we cannot see your screen from here.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry dear for it...Actually Error is : `SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle date arithmetics, subtracting two dates results in the number of days between the two dates:

```
SQL> SELECT DATE '2000-12-31' - DATE '2000-01-01' year FROM DUAL;

      YEAR
----------
       365
```

Your `WHERE` clause is therefore incorrect to Oracle since it cannot compare a number to a date. What exactly do you want to express with this comparison?

If you want to filter all dates before a given date, just compare the two dates:

```
SELECT * FROM SS.EMPLOYEE WHERE joindate <= to_date('2011-12-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
```

If you want to select all rows that are in a given interval, you can use multiple comparisons or the operator `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM SS.EMPLOYEE 
 WHERE joindate BETWEEN to_date('2011-12-05', 'yyyy-mm-dd') AND SYSDATE
```

#### Update

The number of months between two dates is given by the function [`MONTHS_BETWEEN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions102.htm#i78039). You would compare the result of this function to a number (of months).

Comment: I want months after substracting date...I mean to say i want total months.

Comment: Use `MONTHS_BETWEEN` to get the number of months between two dates. It is still not clear what you want to achieve: the employees that have joined since X months ago?